# Reading different properties for different cluster/node

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have developed a hybrid worklight app and everything is set up. Now my case is that I have a load balance and two clusters. These two clusters have been synchronized with only one WAR file. Due to some reason, we have a server java file in the WAR for sharing some global variables with worklight adapters.

The problem now is that these 2 clusters are working independently (will be redirected by the load balance). The global variables in the JAVA file inside their WAR will not be shared. How can we maintain only one set of global variable in this case?

Or is there any method for the JAVA to read the current cluster detail(for example cluster id or IP address) so that I can write logic to point to different properties in worklight.properties

[PS: not good at English. I will clarify more if you guys don't understand me]

Comment: The war files are created and deployed in both the workligt server in the Cluster's right.

Comment: and one more doubt is your properties that you say are static variables which are changed manually right

Comment: @KawineshSK yes, I have only one WAR file deploying to 2 worklight servers serving as cluster. To your second question, yes. If the approach is to read from worklight.properties , I would like to , lets say, hard code 2 sets of different variables for different cluster to read. If the approach is to read from the JAVA file , since each of cluster has the same JAVA file , if i declare a variable inside the JAVA file, they will not share the variable.

Comment: let me explain more about the scenario. I have some login and password encrypted on worklight.properties. If cluster A use this login and password to work. It is okay. But the case if the cluster B at the same time use the same set of username and password to work. Cluster A will expire. So any suggested approach for this?

Comment: Are you saying about login inside your application or worklight console login.

Comment: the login is used for webservice inside worklight adapter

Comment: k ill explain you how the worklight cluster works. First when a request from user1 is accepted my one server in the worklight lets say that server1 and till the server goes down it will receive all the  request from user1. lets say that now the server has gone down and the user1 request goes to server2 if you have worklight based login then you have to login your user again to make him work because the clusters in worklight server dont share a single login profile when used worklight authetication. so in your case there is no way of sharing single user autication sharing between two servers .

Comment: umm... do you mean the load balance will switch to another cluster only when one server is down? not the case when cluster A is busy and let cluster B to balance the work load?

Comment: No i am saying that if that happens due to any reason it may be busy or server crashed or anything worklight server cant maintain a single server login instance for two clusters.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need here is **not** to use static variables to share this information.

I suggest using Redis or Memcached (or some other free solution) to share information across the cluster.

A simpler solution (but less efficient) can be using an SQL database to store/load those shared properties. You can actually create a "configuration" adapter (SQL adapter) which will be called by the other adapters to read/write the configuration properties.